# LibreOffce writer does not hyphenate (English UK, dictionaries are installed)

Tags: libreoffice, language-pack, typography, hunspell

So I enabled hyphenation for my text style, but LibreOffice writer does not hyphenate a single line in a four pages text, obviously having a problem. If I call *Tools* > *Language* > *Hyphenation...* I get an error:

[image]

Which I think is a *wrong* error message. The language set is correctly installed, for example spellchecking works without problem. I went into the suggested dialog, nothing hints at anything being wrong:

[image]

What might cause the problem?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 4):

The last screenshot is a bit misleading. The bold face 'Hyphenation' suggests that such package is present, when in fact it's *not*. If it was present, there would be a child in the tree.

To install

```
sudo apt install hyphen-en-gb
```

Then after restarting LibreOffice, the document is hyphenated.

Comment: This is still the correct answer more than 2.5 years later with LO version 7.0.3.1 on KDE neon 5.20. I had the error message "missing hyphenation data", maybe quoting this here helps people find this solution more quickly.